# Custom Open Graph Story failing Facebook review

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook app has failed review and the only feedback is "Your Open Graph story did not publish on any of the configured platforms."

The only configured platform is iOS. I uploaded a simulator build of the iOS app and created a test user they can use for review. The custom open graph can be created with success repeatedly using the submitted iOS app. I provided very explicit step-by-step instructions. I am using the Facebook-iOS-SDK 3.13.1.

Has anyone successfully addressed this rejection from Facebook review? Is there any way to get better information regarding the obstacle they're encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the feedback "Your Open Graph story did not publish on any of the configured platforms" is generic (too generic to be useful) and can mean a number of things. In my case they could not run the iOS build I submitted in the simulator.

Here's what I learned about submitting your iOS build to Facebook:

- If your app is not on the app store you must upload a simulator build for them to test with.
- Use the command-line xcodebuild tool to create a .app file to upload
- If your app is part of a workspace (e.g. you use CocoaPods) use something like: *xcodebuild -workspace .xcworkspace -scheme  -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1*
- They use [ios-sim](https://github.com/appcelerator/ios-sim) to run your uploaded build. You can install ios-sim via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to test the build before you submit to Facebook
- You must explicitly specify ipad family if your app is iPad only *ios-sim launch .app --sdk 7.1 --family ipad*

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an issue with your app. If you get this approval, it means that the Facebook team have failed to publish the Open Graph story to a Facebook timeline. Every time I've had this, it's been an issue with my app.

**My advice would be:**

1. Log out of your personal FB account, revoke all permissions
2. Re-log in, confirming everything works for your personal account
3. Create 2-3 test users in Facebook and login to your app with each of them in turn, verifying the Open Graph story publishes successfully.

With all the access tokens and permissions flying around, it's pretty easy to make a mistake.